# How do you rename a file with the just assigned auto increment id from mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, image, file-upload, rename

I am working on a form which should upload an image to my server and at the same time give it a id in the db so i can display it to the right user later on. My question is how to rename the file to the id which my mysql has given it? in my database the name for the autoincrement field is 'pictureID'. I'd like to take the value in it and name my picture like that while transfering it to my server :)

Here is my code which is mostly from w3school hehe(mysql and php aren't my strong sites)

the $_POST variables are coming from the already submitted picture..

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["goOnGallery"]) OR isset($_POST["goOnCamera"])){

        // Create connection
        $mysqliConnection = mysqli_connect($mysqliHost, $mysqliUser, $mysqliPassword, $mysqliDatabase);
        // Check connection
        if (!$mysqliConnection) {die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());}

        $insertOfData = "INSERT INTO styles (userID,pictureLikes,pictureDislikes,pictureGender) VALUES ('$userID', '0', '0', '$userGender')";

        if (mysqli_query($mysqliConnection, $insertOfData)) {
            $target_dir = "userarchive/".$userID."/pictures/mystyles/";
            $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["imageUpload"]["name"]);
            $uploadOk = 1;
            $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            // Check file size
            if ($_FILES["imageUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
                echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
            // Allow certain file formats
            if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
                echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
            // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
            if ($uploadOk == 0) {
                echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
            // if everything is ok, try to upload file
            } else {
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imageUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["imageUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
                } else {
                    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $insertOfData . "<br>" . mysqli_error($mysqliConnection);
        }
        mysqli_close($mysqliConnection);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close! Just use these lines:

```
   if (mysqli_query($mysqliConnection, $insertOfData)) {
        $pictureID = mysqli_insert_id($mysqliConnection);
        $fe = substr($_FILES["imageUpload"]["name"], strrpos($_FILES["imageUpload"]["name"], '.'));
        $target_dir = "userarchive/".$userID."/pictures/mystyles/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . $pictureID.$fe);
```

Comment: perfect thanks :) do you know how i can, after the image is sucessfully transered, kind of destroy the form 'posted' stuff so that when i refresh nothing gets posted again? this is happening all the time right now and my db if filling with dublicates :/ @webjuju

Comment: that is certainly a new question, but have a look at the php function header(); as a start (and be sure you have allowed no output before using it...that's the biggest pitfall there).

Answer (score 0):

CODE :

```
//Replace this with $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["imageUpload"]["name"]);
//mysql_query to find last most id in table : 

$res = mysqli_query($mysqliConnection, 'SELECT MAX(file_id) FROM table_name')

//Get Its result into some $fid variable.
$fid = while ($result1 = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
result1['file_id']
} ;
$fid= $fid+1;
//now to name your file as FILE_ID
$target_file = $fid ;
```

This is all you want to insert into your code .